# How to make the property of an object a type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, object-literal

I want to have an object literal, a, and have it's property, b, be string. Not *a* string, but the type string.
Example:
    let a = { b: type string } /* Doesn't work */
Is it even possible? If so, how? And yes I know you can use namespaces but I want to know how to do it with pure object literals.

Comment: "*Not a string, but the type string.*" I'm not sure what are you trying to say. You want an object that that contains an abstract concept as a value? Can you perhaps give us your concrete problem you're trying to solve because this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't assign a *type* as a value because types don't actually exist within the language - they are a meta-concept that the compiler uses to do your type check.

Comment: Depending on what you're looking for, `{ b: "string" }` might get you close. `typeof "something" === b`